# Need to send python requests fast with requests library

Tags: python, web, python-requests

for a couple of days now, I have been trying to find a way to send mass amounts of requests at the same time. I have tried multiprocessing and somewhat threading. Nothing has been too successful for me. Would prefer if the method way is to call a function. Haven't really poked at grequests and stuff because I couldn't find too many resources. I do alot of projects like this and value how known it is.

Code trying to speed up:

```
def ready():
global count2
while thing:
    #runs through thingy to make sure all accounts will not have security questions 
    change = requests.post("#####", data = {'###': token, 'answer0': question, '##': questionid, 'answer1': question, '####': #####, 'answer2': question, 'questionId2': ###} , cookies=cookie, proxies=proxies2)
    count2 += 1
    print(change.content + " Proxy: " + lines[count2])
    if count2 == 50:
        done = True
        print("Done With Challenges!")
        thingy()
    else:
        return ready
        print("wrong")
```

I appriciate any help thank you!

Comment: Also if this helps, the goal of this program is for the the server to get the post request at the millisecond that the server accepts it at.

Comment: I also have that time, so i am basically trying to brute force for that time.

Comment: have you tried `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool.imap_unordered` yet? It is good for async requests if you don't care about the order of responses.

Comment: Hmm, I have tried many other multiprocessing pools, maybe not this one. I'll try right now

Comment: I tried `multiprocessing.Pool` and it realy execute in parallel. Code example: `import datetime
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
  return 'Job: ', x, datetime.datetime.now()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print 'Start', datetime.datetime.now()

  p = Pool(5)
  print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))

  print 'End', datetime.datetime.now()
`
[Reference 16.6.2.9. Process Pools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: Sorry for stupid question, but how would I translate this into requests? I have this so far:

'import datetime
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
import requests


def f(x):
    r = requests.get("######")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    print(p.map(f, ))
'

Comment: Actually, got it working. Didn't change anything, still goes same speed @TaunBA

Comment: For the kind of things you're looking for, grequests looks like a much better library to use. https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests You can generate the required URLs to post and use this.

Comment: Will look more into this, appreciate it